# Usage of "To Be" in Complex Sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction

The sentence I read was

"At least 22 Americans were reported to been among those killed."

Is it correct? Shouldn't it be

"At least 22 Americans were reported to HAVE been among those killed."

Thanks

Comment: This is a request for proofreading, which is off-topic on this site. If you are trying ask to a question about a specific aspect of learning English, please [edit] your question and rephrase it to be clear what aspect that is. For instance, you might be asking whether the structure *[ "to" + past participle ]* is ever correct, particularly in this instance. Please also tell us the source of this sentence, and a link, if possible. Thanks!

Comment: The source of the sentence: 
https://join1440.com/newsletter/gaza-goes-dark-nasas-new-mission-and-a-fat-bear-champ

The whole paragraph is as follows:
The death toll in Israel, primarily from the initial attack and almost entirely civilians, has risen to at least 1,200. At least 22 Americans were reported to been among those killed. At least 1,100 Palestinians—including children, though sources vary on exact figures—have been killed in retaliatory strikes by Israel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct that the sentence is incorrect.

Some alternatives (your solution is the first one):

> At least 22 Americans were reported to have been among those killed.

> At least 22 Americans were reported to be among those killed.